# How to compare the values in a Dictionary using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a function that returns a Dictionary. Key = Players, Value = Score.
Now I want to compare the scores and create a new Dictionary with the new rearanged list where the top score is on top.

Whenever I use GroupBy, it creates automatically Dictionary

so if I do something like this

```
Dictionary<string, int> player = playersRank.getRoundRank ().GroupBy (v => v.Value).Select(k => k.Key);
```

I get a `Dictionary<int, <string,int>>`

How can I order them by value but get Dictionary in return?

Comment: I'm trying to follow. You want to sort, but you use GroupBy ?

Comment: Yeah just because I saw a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584253/c-sharp-how-to-compare-dictionary-values . But could be wrong with this approach in this case

Comment: A dictionary isn't ordered. Any reason you don't just sort it when you need them in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result collection can not be a dictionary because a dictionary is not a ordered collection. You have some options, for example you could use a List of `KeyValuePair`

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> sortedScores;
sortedScores = playersRank.getRoundRank().OrderByDescending(v => v.Value).ToList();
```

You could use many other types too (or even create your own class), it all depends on how you plan on using this list of sorted scores after you create it. If you update your question with more details we may be able to give you better answers on what type of collection you should use.